# SQLite database and CursorLoaders

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm working on a client-side android application that will retrieve data from an URL and save it in a local Database. I am familiarized with using `SQLiteDatabase` for this operation.

My concern began when I was reading about `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display the tables' rows in a list. That's when I read about `CursorLoader` for asynchronously manage the cursor.

The thing is that when reading about it, they talk about `ContentProvider` and as far as I know, that class is used to share data between apps, so I got super confused.

Can you guide me through this, I don't know if I do need to use a `CursorLoader` because I don't know what is it for, and what does it has to do with `ContentProvider` and sharing data between apps.

EDIT: Reading the demo app found in here https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/demo/ConstantsBrowser.java

Seems like to retrieve data it is done in the line 122: onCreateLoader

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(this, db, "SELECT _ID, title, value "
        + "FROM constants ORDER BY title", null);

    return(loader);
}
```

does that means I can no longer use SQLiteDatabase#query() method? like db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

ContentProviders were designed at first to share data across apps, but they offer great advantages for accessing an SQLite database (simple API, ContentResolver and SyncAdapter integration, etc.).

This talk will help you understand the advantages of using a ContentProvider to achieve what you want:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

As you may know, you're not supposed to perform database queries (and I/O operations in general) on the UI thread. Therefore, a CursorLoader can access the database for you in a background thread and deliver the result Cursor on the UI thread. The CursorLoader uses the ContentResolver interface to access your ContentProvider implementation that will execute your query and return the Cursor.

Comment: but using ContentProvider is an alternative to using SQLite database or something?

Comment: No! This is just a simple interface for CRUD operations. You have to implement your own ContentProvider that directly accesses your database.

Comment: actually, I just read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#BeforeYouStart and I don't seem to need a content provider at all, should I use it anyway? and if yes, why?

Comment: It may provide you with some advantages (watch the video). If you prefer not using it, you can use Commonsware's SQLiteCursorLoader: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/loaderex/SQLiteCursorLoader.java

Comment: The ContentProvider/ContentResolver approach also facilitates the implementation of the observer pattern. Your activities can be aware of data changes. These benefits are shown in the video, it is really worth watching! :D

Comment: Let me try to understand it in a programmer's perspective: in order to refresh a ListView with new data I need to add a new row to the database's table. If I want to use SimpleCursorLoader to show those rows, I need a CursorLoader so that it automatically refreshes the listview. At last, to use a cursor loader I need somehow ContentProvider. please correct me if any of this is wrong (:  (already watched the video, but the patterns seems more complex, and  I have never used contentprovider or services before)

Comment: Yes, you are right, the CursorLoader was made to work with a ContentProvider, you can't use it other way. If you think you need something simpler, go with the SQLiteCursorLoader.

Comment: I understand, seems like I'm going to go with it, could you point me to a tutorial where I can get an example of how to implement the code. I'm real blank here

Comment: Commonsware provides an example app in his repository: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

Comment: Yes, it does. The `onCreateLoader()` method needs to return a `Loader`. Loaders are objects that encapsulate the data retrieval logic. In this case, the `SQLiteCursorLoader` will run `SQLiteDatabase#query()` for you.